# Techniques for increasing python pandas speed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large (3MM Record) File.

The file contains four columns: [id, startdate, enddate, status] there will be multiple status changes for each id, my goal is to transpose this data and end up with a wide dataframe with the following columns:

```
[id, status1, status2, status3... statusN]
```

Where the values of the rows will be id, and the startdate of the status on the columns.

An example of a row would be:

```
["xyz", '2020-08-24 23:42:54', '(blank)', '2020-08-26 21:23:45'...(startdate value for status N)]
```

I have written a script that does the following: iterate through all the rows of the first dataframe, and store the status in a set, that way, there are no duplicates and I can get an adequate list of all the statuses.

```
df = pd.read_csv('statusdata.csv')
columns = set()
columns.add('id')
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    columns.add(row['status'])
```

Then I create a new dataframe with the columns 'id' and then all the other statuses taken from the Set

```
columnslist = list(columns)
newdf = pd.DataFrame(columns = columnslist)
newdf = newdf[['id']+[c for c in newdf if c not in ['id']]] #this will make 'id' the first column
```

Then I iterate through all the columns of the original dataframe and create a new record in the new dataframe if the id it's reading is not already in the dataframe, and then log the startdate of the status indicated in the original df on its matching column in the new df.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
        if row['opportunityid'] not in newdf['id']:
            newdf.loc[len(newdf), 'id'] = row['opportunityid']
        newdf.loc[newdf['id'] == row['opportunityid'], row['status']] = row['startdate']
```

My concern is with the speed of the code. At this rate it will take 13+ hrs to go through all the lines of the original dataframe to transpose it into this new dataframe with unique keys. Is there a way to make this more efficient? Is there a way to allocate more memory from my computer? Or is there a way to deploy this code on aws or another cloud computing software to make it run faster? I'm currently running this on a 2020 13 inch mac book pro with 32 GB of ram.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you could do this without iterating.  First, create sample data:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as 

data = '''id, start, end, status
A, 1, 10, X
A, 2, 20, Y
A, 3, 30, Z
A, 9, 99, Z
B, 4, 40, W
B, 5, 50, X
B, 6, 60, Y
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep=', ', engine='python')
print(df)

  id  start  end status
0  A      1   10      X
1  A      2   20      Y
2  A      3   30      Z
3  A      9   99      Z  # <- same id + status as previous row
4  B      4   40      W
5  B      5   50      X
6  B      6   60      Y
```

Second, select the columns of interest (everything but `end`); set `id` and `start` to row labels; `squeeze()` to ensure the object is converted to a pandas Series; and finally put `status` as column labels:

```
t = (df[['id', 'start', 'status']]
     .groupby(['id','status'], as_index=False)['start'].max() # <- new
     .set_index(['id', 'status'], verify_integrity=True)
     .sort_index()
     .squeeze()
     .unstack(level='status')
    )
print(t)
status    W    X    Y    Z
id                        
A       NaN  1.0  2.0  9.0
B       4.0  5.0  6.0  NaN
```

The NaN values show what happens when there is not 100 percent overlap in `status`.

UPDATE

I added a row of data to cause duplicate (id, status) pair.  Also added `groupby()` method to pull out latest (id, status) pair.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the prompt response, after running your very elegant script I got a ValueError, Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape. Since this is the first time i've seen this type of df manipulation i'm not sure why this would be. Your sample df should cover all of the cases in my df. you have duplicate id's and duplicate statuses, one thing that I might add is that the "start" might also be duplicated.

Comment: Edit:  one thing I can think of is that there might exist instances where an [id, status] pair exists twice (in the case where a status was rolled back for example, and then re promoted), how could I deal with this?

Comment: Hi, I added `groupby()` to pull the latest start for this case.  You could modify the groupby() statement to get earliest start, latest end, etc.

Comment: You sir are a genius. Thank you! Where do you learn from? I'm open to improve my skills.

Comment: Thanks!  I have spent a lot of time with the pandas docs, including https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html#min -- it took me a _lot_more than 10 minutes.  Another source is https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf (it's focus is R, but the concepts translate).